# Coin toss and Combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A fair coin is tossed 10 times. Find the probability $p$ that at the eighth toss but not earlier heads show for the second time.

My approach is to think of it as:

- $p_1$ (Seven tosses contains 1 H) $= 7 \times 0.5^7 $
- $p_2$ (Eighth toss equals H) $= 0.5$
- And then, $p_1\times p_2 = 0.0273$

But in the textbook, the correct answer is $7/128 = 0.0546$

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Your book has a calculation error.

The probability for obtaining the second head on the eighth toss is:

$$7\cdot (0.5)^7\times (0.5) = 7/256 = 0.027\,343\,75$$